# Serializing/Deserializing an existing class which don't have a serialize member

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm trying to serialize the [NTL::ZZ_p](http://file:///home/bush/Desktop/ASIO/ntl-9.1.0/doc/ZZ_p.cpp.html) class so I could send it over the network. For completeness - the class has no serialization methods:

```
class ZZ_p {
public:

   ZZ_p(); // initialize to 0

   ZZ_p(const ZZ_p& a); // copy constructor
   explicit ZZ_p(long a);  // promotion constructor

   ~ZZ_p(); // destructor

   ZZ_p& operator=(const ZZ_p& a); // assignment
   ZZ_p& operator=(long a); // assignment

   static void init(const ZZ& p);
   // ZZ_p::init(p) sets the modulus to p (p > 1)

   static const ZZ& modulus();
   // ZZ_p::modulus() yields read-only reference to the current
   // modulus

   // typedefs to aid in generic programming
   typedef ZZ rep_type;
   typedef ZZ_pContext context_type;
   typedef ZZ_pBak bak_type;
   typedef ZZ_pPush push_type;
   typedef ZZ_pX poly_type;
};
```

but in the same file there are two functions:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& s, const ZZ_p& a);
istream& operator>>(istream& s, ZZ_p& x);
```

Generally I would like to use boost to serialize it but ostream/istream are okay as well.

Can you tell me how to serialize it?

So far I did in my class (`id` is integer, `k0,k1` are `NTL::ZZ_p`):

```
friend class boost::serialization::access;

  template<typename Archive>
  void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned version) {
    ar & id;
    ar << k0;
    ar << k1;  // Simply serialize the data members of MyObj
  }
```

and to send it I do:

```
PreProcess1 pp1(iter->first, iter2->second[0], iter2->second[1]);
std::string msg;
std::stringstream ss;
boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ss);
int msg_type = PRE_PROCESS_1;
ar & msg_type & pp1;
msg = ss.str();
mComm->Send(iter2->first, msg.c_str(), msg.size());
```

and I'm getting the error:

```
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:118:9: error: ‘class NTL::ZZ_p’ has no member named ‘serialize’
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that you do not show the line that produces the error. How do you call the method?

Comment: Added code that seems relevant

Comment: Just a guess - perhaps you want your function 'serialize()' to be a method of ZZ_p?

Comment: It was easiest if that was the case. But unfortunately it's not. So I'm asking whether I can work around this.

Comment: I am still pretty sure that you do not show the line that produces the error. The error looks like you have a `zz_p->serialize` somewhere, where `zz_p` is a `ZZ_p`. Where do you call the `serialize` method?